# Selecting a variable's nested elements - jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I wish to pass a variable to a function and have the function select elements within that variable. I'm unfamiliar with the syntax of this case however, could any one advise?

For example, when a button is clicked within a container I wish for that container to be stored in a variable, okay I have that part. But then I wish to select a certain element within that container like

```
$(container "div#element");
```

How can you combine the two, noting that these elements could be deeply nested?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jQuery gets a second parameter, which determines the scope of the selection. For example `$('#first-name', '#registration-form')` only matches elements with the `first-name` id inside `registration-form`.

I guess you can use this feature. I think `$("div#element", container);` would work.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saeedneamati/FASyK/).

Answer (score 7):

For chainability you can also use:

```
$(container).find('#element');
```

Comment: Just one note: no need to specify redundant div part since #id is already enough.

Answer (score 2):

Use `find` if you are searching the Dom.

```
function doSomething(container) {
  var $element = $(container).find('#element');

  // .. Now do something

}
```

Use `filter` if you are wanting to search only the elements contained by container.

```
function doSomething(container) {
  var $element = $(container).filter('#element');

  // .. Now do something

}
```